# checkinstal - dpkg -r does not remove the package

Tags: make, dpkg, checkinstall

I have installed a tool form source code with checkinstall. The installation was fine. That is the output:

```
Done. The new package has been installed and saved to

 /opt/ntopng-2.0/ntopng_2.0-1_armhf.deb

 You can remove it from your system anytime using:

      dpkg -r ntopng
```

When I tried to remove it with dpkg -r ntopng command, it seems that nothing is happened:

```
root@raspberrypi:/opt/ntopng-2.0#       dpkg -r ntopng
(Reading database ... 93161 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ntopng ...
dpkg: warning: while removing ntopng, directory '/usr/local/share' not empty so not removed
dpkg: warning: while removing ntopng, directory '/usr/local/bin' not empty so not removed
Processing triggers for man-db ...

root@raspberrypi:/opt/ntopng-2.0# ls -l
total 48164
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi   pi        383 May 31 22:07 autogen.sh
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root     4096 Nov 17 13:31 autom4te.cache
-rwxr-xr-x  1 pi   pi      43423 May 31 22:07 config.guess
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    25263 Nov 17 13:56 config.log
-rwxrwxr-x  1 root root    28733 Nov 17 13:56 config.status
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   157230 Nov 17 13:30 configure
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    10712 Nov 17 13:29 configure.ac
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi      10722 May 31 22:07 configure.seed
drwxr-xr-x  3 pi   pi       4096 May 31 22:07 contrib
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi      35147 May 31 22:07 COPYING
-rw-r--r--  1 root root        7 Nov 17 15:14 description-pak
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi       4096 Nov 17 13:56 doc
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     4096 Nov 17 15:14 doc-pak
drwxr-xr-x 10 pi   pi       4096 May 31 22:07 httpdocs
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi       4096 Nov 17 13:56 include
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi      35142 May 31 22:07 LICENSE
-rw-rw-r--  1 root root     8812 Nov 17 13:56 Makefile
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi       8836 May 31 22:07 Makefile.in
drwxr-xr-x 11 pi   pi       4096 Nov 17 13:37 nDPI
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  9100918 Nov 17 15:13 ntopng
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 39749450 Nov 17 15:28 ntopng_2.0-1_armhf.deb
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi      15594 May 31 22:07 ntopng.8
drwxr-xr-x  5 pi   pi       4096 Nov 17 13:56 packages
-rw-r--r--  1 pi   pi        720 May 31 22:07 README.md
drwxr-xr-x  4 pi   pi       4096 May 31 22:07 scripts
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi       4096 Nov 17 15:13 src
drwxr-xr-x 13 pi   pi       4096 May 31 22:07 third-party
drwxr-xr-x  2 pi   pi       4096 May 31 22:07 tools
```

I rebooted the server and tried again. That is the message received

```
root@raspberrypi:/opt/ntopng-2.0# dpkg -r ntopng
dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove ntopng which isn't installed
```

Any suggestion?

This is the output of `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile /opt/ntopng-2.0/ntopng_2.0-1_armhf.deb | tar t`

```
 root@raspberrypi:/opt/ntopng-2.0# dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile /opt/ntopng-2.0/ntopng_2.0-1_armhf.deb | tar t
./
./usr/
./usr/local/
./usr/local/bin/
./usr/local/bin/ntopng
./usr/local/share/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/vlan_stats_id.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/country_stats_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/flows_stats_bottom.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/header.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/processes_stats_id.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/aggregated_hosts_stats_id.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/index_TopASNs.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/country_stats_id.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/aggregated_hosts_stats_bottom.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/http_servers_stats_id.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/processes_stats_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/hosts_stats_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/os_stats_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/as_stats_id.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/host_to_server_id.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/network_stats_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/hosts_stats_bottom.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/flows_stats_middle.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/index_TopApplications.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/index_TopFlowSenders.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/sprobe_process.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/sflows_stats_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/flows_stats_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/network_stats_id.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/http_servers_stats_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/host_to_server_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/hosts_stats_id.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/index_TopHosts.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/sprobe_process_header.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/processes_stats_bottom.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/as_stats_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/index_TopPorts.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/geolocation_disclaimer.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/aggregated_hosts_stats_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/sflows_stats_bottom.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/flows_stats_id.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/os_stats_id.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/inc/vlan_stats_top.inc
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/cubism.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/flags.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/bubble-chart.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/sequence_sunburst.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/tablesorted.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/datepicker.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/cal-heatmap.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/dc.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/nv.d3.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/timepicker.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/timeline.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/bootstrap-duallistbox.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/jquery-ui.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/rickshaw.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/Rickshaw/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/Rickshaw/detail.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/Rickshaw/graph.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/Rickshaw/legend.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/c3.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/ntopng.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/pagingbar.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/pie-chart.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/bootstrap-slider.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/css/prettify.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/favicon.ico
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/nv.d3.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/c3.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/springyui-ntop.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/jquery.form.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/README.gauge
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/bootstrap.ajaxpager-0.8.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/ntopng_utils.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/highlight.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/rickshaw.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/pdfmake.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/d3.v3.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/bootstrap-slider.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/cubism.v1.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/dc.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/jquery.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/markerclusterer.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/jquery.peity.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/sequence_sunburst.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/html5shiv.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/cal-heatmap.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/jquery.bootstrap-duallistbox.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/timeline.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/bootstrap-datatable.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/pie-chart.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/bootstrap3-typeahead.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/springy-ntop.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/cpu_bar.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/jquery-ui.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/jquery.tablesorter.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/prettify.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/crossfilter.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/bubble-chart.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/gauge.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/line-graph.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/moment.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/handlebars-1.0.0.0.beta.6.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/jquery.sparkline.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/vfs_fonts.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/sankey.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/googleMapJson.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/js/matrix_volume.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/loading.gif
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/flags.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/os_icon.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/info_icon.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/block-end.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/m5.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/m1.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/conv30.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/people55.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/heart30.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/people35.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/people45.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/m3.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/m2.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/heart40.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/m4.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/conv40.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/conv50.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/maps/heart50.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/info.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/network_icon.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/graph.gif
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/throbber.gif
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/interaction-graph-icons/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/interaction-graph-icons/ntopng.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/interaction-graph-icons/redis-server.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/interaction-graph-icons/apache2.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/interaction-graph-icons/nprobe.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/interaction-graph-icons/firefox.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/interaction-graph-icons/sprobe.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/interaction-graph-icons/java.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/interaction-graph-icons/remote_hosts.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/blank.gif
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/logo.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/warning.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/desc.gif
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/asc.gif
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/block-start.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/img/cpu_icon.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/geoip/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/geoip/GeoLiteCityv6.dat
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/geoip/GeoIPASNumv6.dat
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/geoip/GeoLiteCity.dat
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/geoip/GeoIPASNum.dat
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/geoip/README
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/test.lp
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/css/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/js/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/fonts/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/img/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/css/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_stacked.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_variables.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_fixed-width.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_rotated-flipped.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_larger.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_bordered-pulled.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_path.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_icons.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_mixins.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_core.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_list.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/scss/_animated.scss
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/fonts/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/fonts/FontAwesome.otf
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/icons.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/path.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/animated.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/fixed-width.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/rotated-flipped.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/variables.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/stacked.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/font-awesome.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/list.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/bordered-pulled.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/larger.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/core.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/font-awesome/less/mixins.less
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/ssl/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/httpdocs/ssl/README
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/callbacks/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/callbacks/second.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/callbacks/daily.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/callbacks/minute.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/callbacks/hourly.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_http_hosts_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_host_contacts.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/hosts_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/show_alerts.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_host_activitymap.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_epp_breakdown.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/processes_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/inc/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/inc/add_user_dialog.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/inc/search_host_box.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/inc/password_dialog.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/inc/sprobe.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/inc/footer.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/inc/menu.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/inc/users.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/inc/delete_user_dialog.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/inc/change_user_password_form.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/inc/sankey.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/sflows_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/iface_hosts_list.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_host_traffic_matrix.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/as_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_hosts_interaction.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_grouped_hosts_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_process_info.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/aggregated_hosts_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/iface_ports_list.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_top_peers_protocols.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/page_not_found.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/hosts_flows_matrix.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/aggregated_host_details.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/aggregated_host_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/if_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/hosts_comparison_bubble.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/set_if_prefs.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/user_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/popKeys.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/sprobe_hosts.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/os_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_pkt_distro.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/sprobe_host_process_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/sprobe_hosts_interactions_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/sprobe.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_aggregated_host_info.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/examples/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/examples/sqlite.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/examples/debug.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/examples/hello_world.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/examples/interface.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/examples/ntop.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/flows_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/sprobe_hosts_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/sprobe_host_process.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_flows_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/sprobe_flow_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/network_load.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_alerts_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_host_traffic.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_http_breakdown.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_sflow_distro.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/sprobe_hosts_interactions.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_user_info.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_http_hosts.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/iface_ndpi_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/flow_details.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_host_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/interface_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/hosts_interaction.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/hosts_matrix.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_details.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/API.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_details_ndpi.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/lua_trace.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/top_talkers.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/influx_utils.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/template.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/voip_utils.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/sqlite_utils.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/traffic_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/flow_utils.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/lua_utils.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/top_scripts/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/top_scripts/top_asn.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/top_scripts/top_talkers.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/top_scripts/top_networks.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/top_scripts/top_countries.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/top_scripts/top_os.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/top_scripts/top_vlan.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/top_scripts/top_os_local.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/persistence.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/top_structure.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/dkjson.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/json.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/get_real_epochs.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/alert_utils.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/modules/graph_utils.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/login.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/logout.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/if_stats_ndpi.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/flow_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/if_pkt_distro.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/do_export_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_get_json.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_geo_hosts.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/system_hosts_interaction.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/vlan_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_flow_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/port_details.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/protocols/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/protocols/epp_aggregations.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/protocols/dns_aggregations.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_l4_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/admin/
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/admin/change_user_prefs.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/admin/get_user_info.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/admin/users.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/admin/change_user_password.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/admin/get_users.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/admin/add_user.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/admin/delete_user.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/admin/prefs.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/admin/validate_new_user.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/admin/password_reset.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/pid_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/iface_flows_sankey.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/about.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/country_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/network_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/hosts_comparison.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/db.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/hosts_comparison_sankey.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/hosts_treemap.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_top_talkers.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_filter_host.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/top_hosts.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/host_dns_breakdown.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/top_generic.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_host_daily_activity.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/iface_local_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/set_active_interface.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/find_host.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_treemap.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/sflow_tree.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/export_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/config_historical_interface.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/resolve_address.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_processes_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/test_snmp.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/http_servers_stats.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_system_hosts_interaction.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/hosts_geomap.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/index.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/sprobe_data.lua
./usr/local/share/ntopng/scripts/lua/get_hosts_data.lua
./usr/local/man/
./usr/local/man/man8/
./usr/local/man/man8/ntopng.8.gz
./usr/share/
./usr/share/doc/
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/LICENSE
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/README.md
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/README.SSL
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/README.ntopng
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/UserGuide.pages
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/README.txt
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/README.httpbl
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/README.users
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/README.nagios
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/README.docker_openstack
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/UserGuide.pdf
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/README.netfilter
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/doxygen.conf
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/README.windows
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/doxygen.conf.in
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/README.categorization
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/mainpage.dox
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/doc/README.vagrant
./usr/share/doc/ntopng/COPYING
```

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile  /opt/ntopng-2.0/ntopng_2.0-1_armhf.deb | tar t`?

Comment: Hi Muru, I have added in the description. Thanks

Comment: And do any of those files exist on your system?

Comment: No they don't but the software is still available and ti works. I thought tha dpkg -r would have dis-installed the software...

Comment: I'll tell you what I have done step by step:

cd /opt/
wget http://....... + library
tar xvzf 
./autogen.sh
auto-apt run ./configure
make
checkinstall

The, what is happened in background...not sure :)

Comment: I mean that when I try to start the software in this way
/opt/ntopng-2.0# ./ntopng
The software start and it works.
If I remove a package I aspect to remove the entire software and I aspect to do not have more the software installed. Make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31704/discussion-between-federi-and-muru).

Comment: Mate...your answers they don't help me as well as the conversation that we had on chat. As you maybe understood I' m not big expert in this stuff and if you want help me you need to be little bit more patient and give more description to your answers otherwise they will not very useful for me. If you don't have don't worry, someone else will help me.
Also, please don't edit your comments and show to everyone how mean have you been.Take the responsibility of what you have written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three directory trees involved when you build a program from source code:

- the source directory. It can be practically anywhere you choose. In your case, it appears to be `/opt/ntopng-2.0`.
- the object or build directory. This is where the compiler and other actions done by `make` will create all the object and executable files. It is often located in a subdirectory of the source directory, but in your case it looks like it's the same as the source directory.
- the installation or target directory. This is where `make install` will copy the executable files that `make` built, as well as any support files. The installation directory usually defaults to `/usr/local`. Typically, the executables will be copied to `/usr/local/bin` and the support files to `/usr/local/lib` or `/usr/local/share`. You can choose a directory other than `/usr/local` by giving `./configure` a `--prefix=/path/to/other/directory` option.

Sometimes programs will work just fine, or almost fine, if you run the copies in the object directory. Sometimes programs won't work at all because they need to read support files from the installation directory. In your case, `/opt/ntopng-2.0/ntopng` appears to run, even though it was meant to be run from `/usr/local/bin/ntopng`.

[`checkinstall`](https://www.debian-administration.org/article/147/Installing_packages_from_source_code_with_checkinstall) does a `make install`, and it monitors what is installed, then it writes appropriate files and instructions into a `.deb` file in your current directory that will enable `dpkg` to install and uninstall the files.

checkinstall can only monitor the effects of `make install` (or whatever command it was told to execute). So running `dpkg -r` with the `.deb` file created by `checkinstall` cannot affect the contents of the source or object directories. You'll need to remove them manually.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Finally I understood. Thanks Mark